# Show Error Rd is not defined when use Function in chrome.scripting.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, vite

I'm developing a chrome extension using react and vitejs.

My **manifest.json** file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "DEV Articles",
  "description": "DEV",
  "version": "0.0.1",
     "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent",
        "scripting"
    ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
   
}
```

when I use an imported function in `chrome.scripting.executeScript`  the  `Uncaught ReferenceError: Rd is not defined` error is displayed in the chrome console

**App.jsx**:

```
import { test } from './test'

const  App = () => {

  const handleClick = async () => {

    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active : true}); 

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target :{ tabId: tab.id },
      func:()=>{
          test()        
      }
    })
  }

  return <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        click 
      </button>
    </>
  
}

export default App
```

**Test.jsx**:

```
const test = () => {
  console.log("Hello")
}

export { test }
```

This error is not displayed when I do not use this imported method